# Play a video when dragged into an area with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to find a way to drag a video into a droppable area using JQUery.  When this video is dropped into the area, it will both expand and begin to play.  I also want to be able to drag the video back out and have it stop which allows the user to drag another video in...any ideas on how this would be done??

All I have now is

```
$function () 
{
    $("#drag").draggable();
    $("#drop").droppable(
    {
        drop: function (event, ui) 
        {
            $(this)
                .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")
                .find("p")
                .html("dropped!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should drag only images (thumbnail) of your videos with the url of the associate video as attribute. When an image is dropped, catch the url (using the attribute) and create an HTML 5 video container, then play it programmatically

Comment: That's a good idea, I am pretty new to this stuff so I will give it a try...how would I go about grabbing the URL?  Would it be possible to play in that box? and how would I allow the user to move other videos for playing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/26/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
    <img class="drag" width="200px" videourl="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="image" src="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/wp-content/themes/bunny/graphics/header1.jpg" />

    <video id="video" class="drop" width="320" height="240" controls style="background-color:grey">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".drag").draggable();
    $(".drop").droppable(
    {
        drop: function (event, ui) 
        {
           var url = $(ui.draggable).hide().attr('videourl');
           var $video = $('#video')
           $video.empty().append('<source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" />'); 
           $video.get(0).play();
        }
    });
});
```